# std::string's character reference

Tags: c++, stdstring

I have the following string:

```
index                                       0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
std::string myString with the content of "\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff\x0d\x0a\xf5"
```

When I'm refering to myString[3], I get the expected '\x00' value.

But when I'm referring to myString[5], I get two values "\x0d\x0a" instead of just '\x0d'.

Even more interesting is the myString[6] value, which is the '\xf5'. This time it's like the \x0d didn't exist and the correct position was referenced.

My question would be: what is so special about the \x0d character in a std:string object? How come it is skipped when indexing? It's like counting this way:

```
index                     0   1   2   3   4   5   5   6
std::string myString = "\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff\x0d\x0a\xf5"
```

As a comment, the '\x0d' character is the 13th ASCII character "carriage return" and '\x0a' is the line feed character.

UPDATE: Can it be that std::string considers "\x0d\x0a" as a single character and thus occupies only one position in the string? Is this '\x0d' a "mystery" character with regard to std::string?

ADDITIONAL INFO: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline

Comment: Can you shows this in a small, complete, compilable program? I don't understand how you get two characters when accessing index 5. The `[]` operator only returns one `char`, after all.

Comment: is \x0a line feed? These might be treated as a single character to make a "line break" hold the same number of indexes (one) on systems with varying line break styles, although I'm really not sure as to the internal workings of std::string, so I won't post that as an answer.

Comment: I will continue to add more information to this question. Indeed your hunch might be right: '\x0a' is a line feed, and it seems that std::string treats them as one character: '\x0d\x0a'.

Comment: This isn't possible; `"\x0d\x0a"` just won't fit in a single char.

Comment: I really think we need to see more code -- a complete example that demonstrates the behaviour you observe.

Comment: On my MSVC Team Ed. 2005, This crashes with 'string subscript out-of-range' assertion failure. std::string myString = "\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff\x0d\x0a\xf5"; const char c= myString[4];

Comment: It is really that straight forward. I receive data in a std::string object, and then I am outputting it with myString[3] and myString[5].

Comment: But this dosen't ' std::string myString = "\xff\xff\xff\xff\x0d\x0a\xf5\x00"; const char c = myString[4];'. Does this mean that there is a bug in MSVC string impl. It treats \x00 as end-of-string? Surprised ...

Comment: I will also add the platform details because I'm not compiling with MSVC.

Comment: I think you forgot a `'\0'` there... but the behaviour you're getting is not surprising at all, because "classic" C-style strings are terminated by a null character, and that's what you're initializing the std::string with, so the string is only three characters long. Null characters in `std::string`s are allowed, but you need to be a bit crafty to get them in there... see here, for example: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14676 This is why we really need to see a complete example to figure out what's going on.

Comment: How do you know myString[5] gives you '\x0d\x0a'? Are you visually observing a carriage return followed by a line feed on standard out?

Comment: Yes. I am doing extensive tracing of this string and see in a txt file, using Notepad++, as a HEX viewer, that there are 2 chars instead of one for myString[5] and also the rest of the code's behaviour (extra assertions) indicates that indeed those two bytes are considered as one. I realize that this is VERY unusual but this is what I see.

Comment: @cmdev: Obviously you're following these comments -- can you _please_ post more source code? Independent of that, if you're outputting `myString[5]` to a text file, then it's not surprising that you're seeing `"\x0d\x0a"` in the file, because that's the standard line separator under Windows, and this kind of translation happens when you output to files in "text mode". For example, `fprintf(file, "\n");` will print `"\x0d\x0a"`(aka "\r\n") to the file if it was `fopen`ed with `"wt"`.

Comment: @cmdev: Based on your comment that you're outputting this to a text file, I think I've worked out what is going on. See my edited answer.

Comment: @Martin B: Thank you for figuring out what was going on here. I think you're right about this translation. Also, I want to thank everybody for the replies posted to this question.

Comment: @cmdev: So the problem wasn't in the string, but in IO. Had you tried provided a small, compilable example reproducing this, you would have had an answer within minutes. Heck, you probably would have found this out yourself!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Are you sure this is happening with `std::string`? `std::string::operator[]` returns a `const char &`, so how can it be returning two chars (`'\x0d'` *and* `'\x0a'`)?

That said, `"\x0d\x0a"` is usually used for line endings under Windows, whereas only `'\x0a'` is used under Linux, so conversion of the former to the latter is relatively common under Windows -- for example, I'm thinking of the behaviour of `fopen` when called with `"wt"`. I would guess something similar is happening to you.

*Edit*: Based on your comments on the original question, I think I can guess what's going on.

I believe your string doesn't really contain what you think it contains. You're being misled because the mechanism you're using to output the string to a file (probably `ofstream`?) is performing end-of-line translation. This means that a `'\n'` (the Unix end-of-line code) is being translated to `'\r\n'` (the Windows end-of-line code). The purpose of end-of-line translation is to make code more portable between operating systems. You can inhibit it by opening the file in *binary mode*; for `ofstream`, this is done by specifying the `ios_base::binary` flag when you open the file, but this flag is not set by default.

(See this [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) for more information on end-of-line markers on different operating systems.)

This is what I believe is going on. Your string actually contains

```
index                 0   1   2   3   4   5   6
myString contents  "\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff\x0a\xf5"
```

You're outputting it something like this:

```
ofstream file("myfile.txt");
for(size_t i=0; i<myString.size(); i++)
    ofstream << myString[i];
```

Because of the end-of-line translation expalined above, the `'\x0a'` in `myString[5]` is being output as `'\x0d\x0a'`, and that's what is confusing you.

Comment: Indeed I'm using a similar mechanism: std::ostringstream. Also, if you can add more info about this translation for future reference I would be grateful. For example, who actually does it, and maybe a few links on the web.

Comment: I've added a link to a comprehensive Wikipedia article. As to where the end-of-line translation is actually done, that probably depends on the standard library implementation -- but it probably happens in `ofstream` / `ostringstream` etc. or one of their base classes.

Answer (score 9):

One thing that's going wrong here is the following line doesn't do what you expect:

```
std::string myString = "\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff\x0d\x0a\xf5";
```

This calls the `std::string(const char *)` constructor, which is designed to convert a C-style null-terminated string to a C++ `std::string`. This constructor reads bytes starting at the given pointer and copies them to the new `std::string` until it reaches a null byte (\x00). This is consistent with the behaviour of C functions such as `strlen()`.

So, when your `myString` is constructed, it consists of a string of length 3, with bytes \xff, \xff, \xff. Access to indexes greater than 2 are accessing bytes off the end of the array (which will produce a runtime error at best, or undefined behaviour at worst).

Note that a `std::string` can hold intermediate null bytes, but you *cannot* use the above constructor to initialise such a string because the null byte is interpreted as terminating the C-style string passed to the constructor.

It would be worth trying your code again with the \x00 byte changed to something else, just to see how it differs from what you have already described:

```
std::string myString = "\xff\xff\xff\x01\xff\x0d\x0a\xf5"
```

Also, check `myString.length()` after the above constructor to see what you get.

Comment: O.K. Meaning, the std::string::string(const char* ) ctor, iterates over C-Strings until '\0'. Makes sense why i was seeing the behavior on MSVC. My bad ...

Comment: Good point -- I assumed that cmdev just wanted to show us the contents of the string and wasn't giving us the code that is actually used to initialize the string... but if this is the actual initialization, you've nailed the problem.

Comment: That's correct. What I wanted to show was only the content of the string. The exact assignment is much more complex than this simple assignment. I will add a comment on it.

Comment: While you're at it, can you show us the complete source code that you're using to access and output `myString[5]`? If the string isn't being read from disk, can you also show us the code you're using to initialize the string?

Comment: @cmdev: Don't add a note. Paste a small, compilable program that shows the behavior you describe so that we can paste it into our editors and play with it. Right now the answer upvoted most addresses a point you said is moot. How do you expect to get answers fitting your question if we have to guess what the question is?

Answer (score 2):

You create string with following constructor: `string(char const *)`

It receives NUL terminated C string. So it finds its length according to the first 0 character.

You should use other constructor that specifies size: `string(char const *,size_t n)` by calling:

```
std::string myString("\xff\xff\xff\x00\xff\x0d\x0a\xf5",8);
```

See http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/ for further reading

Answer (score 0):

You are probably misusing the [] operator.

The [] operator returns a const char.  However you are probably using this as a pointer and thus getting two characters - we need to see your actual code to confirm this.

0x00 is a null-terminator for a c-string so that is probably why you are getting only one (correct) character for that.

What happens when you get [4]?

Answer (score 0):

In visual studio 2008, the \x00 is considered the end of string. So myString.lenght returns 3. When you try to access myString[5] you get an error.